# how to retrieve only updated products in long query?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, xml

I have build an xml/aspx page that retrieves all rows in a producttable through sql server. This page is used as an xmlfeed. This xml displays productdetails like name, price and stock etc. Because the query is timeconsuming I would like to only retrieve the rows that have been changed( stock for example). What is the way to go about this in sql server?

sql server

```
select name,price,productid
from product
```

c#

```
public List<Feed> GetFeed()
{
    DataSet dst = new DataSet();
    SqlCommand cmd = null;
    List<Feed> feedlist = new List<Feed>();
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("[GetFeed]", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        using (SqlDataReader rs = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (rs.Read())
            {
                feed feed = new Feed();
                feed.productID = rs["ProductID"].ToString();
                feed.price = rs["price"].ToString();
                feedlist.Add(feed);
            }
            rs.NextResult();
        }
    }
    return feedlist;
}


    public class Feed
{
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ProductID { get; set; }
}


  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 var feeds = GetFeed();
 XElement products =
         new XElement("products",
            from p in feeds
            select new XElement("Product",
                  new XElement("id", p.ProductID),
                  new XElement("Price", p.Price),
                  new XElement("Name", p.Name)

            )
         );

    Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
    Response.Write(products.ToString());
    Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: Please show your query and I am guessing you need a `WHERE` clause to filter down the result set.

Comment: @Karl how can I select the updated rows in the Where clause. Do I need to add a column row modified?

Comment: @user603007 - yes, that would be a good start.

Comment: @Karl still have the issue of updating the updated rows in the existing xmlfile

Answer (score 0):

You’ll need to add another column to your database that shows when row was last updated. It can be as simple as adding a datetime column ModifidedDate. If you want to take this one step further you can even add things like ModifiedBy and such…

Once you complete this just update you stored procedure to include WHERE statement that basically says

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.[GetFeed]
 (
    @LastModification datetime
)
AS 
BEGIN
SELECT *
FROM Products
WHERE ModifiedDate > @LastModification
END
```

You’ll also need to update your code to include parameter for GetFeed method and for SqlCommand object

```
public List<Feed> GetFeed(DateTime lastModification)
{
DataSet dst = new DataSet();
SqlCommand cmd = null;
List<Feed> feedlist = new List<Feed>();
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("[GetFeed]", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LastModification", lastModification));
    using (SqlDataReader rs = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (rs.Read())
        {
            feed feed = new Feed();
            feed.productID = rs["ProductID"].ToString();
            feed.price = rs["price"].ToString();
            feedlist.Add(feed);
        }
        rs.NextResult();
    }
}
return feedlist;
}
```